# libgdx application remove other application from android

Tags: android, gradle

I am developing two games using Libgdx, but when I debug one of the two games on my android device it replaces the other. when I run the android studio, it deletes the other game and take it's place on my device. how to keep them both on my device????

Comment: They must have different applicationId, otherwise it will replace the existing app. Create 2 different productFlavors for each app version and it will work ;)

Comment: where can I change the application Id ?? or I have to start one of the games from the beginning??

Comment: You change that in your gradle configuration file. Are you using gradle?

Comment: yes, I will try to find it

Comment: See my answer it may help ;)

Comment: i found this for the two games  :
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mygdx.game"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
and changed the

        applicationId "com.mygdx.game"
to 
applicationId "com.mygdx.game1"
it works well but is this right and enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample on how to change `productFlavors` in your `gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp"
       ...
    }
    ...

    productFlavors {
        v1 {
            applicationId 'com.yourapp'
        }
        v2 {
            applicationId 'com.yourapp.v2'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now just choose the right flavour (**build variant**) to build with Android Studio and run.

Comment: change id or flavour?

Comment: i found this for the two games : defaultConfig { applicationId "com.mygdx.game" minSdkVersion 8 targetSdkVersion 23 } and changed the applicationId "com.mygdx.game" to applicationId "com.mygdx.game1" it works well but is this right and enough?

Comment: I found application Id but there is no Flavour

Comment: If you've 1 project for both use my solution. If you have 1 project for each game just modify the applicationId in defaultConfig for each project and its right and  enough ;)